# Por que damos o nome de "word" para uma sequência de 2 bytes?

Tags: assembly, convenções-de-nome, arquitetura-computadores

Sou um iniciante no estudo de arquitetura de computadores, e esse nome me deixou um pouco curioso. Já vi que existem word's, doubleword's e quadword's. Mas o por que desse nome dado a 2 bytes e não a 1 simples byte?

Comment: Creio que é uma nomenclatura antiga. Existiram computadores antigos em que a unidade mínima de memória endereçável eram palavras de 16 bits e não bytes.

Comment: Aliás, por que chamar 1 byte de word se ele já se chama byte? xD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Word se refere ao número de bits de uma instrução de processador. O processador que está estudando aparenta usar 16 bits para suas instruções. O tamanho da word é definida pela arquitetura do processador, não algo pré-definido como o byte que tem sempre 8 bits.

Eis uma tabelinha com vários processadores e seus respectivos tamanhos de word:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes